# How to send data from the child component to the specific array in parent component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

When I click on one of the answer button I want to send that dat to to relevant array but the problem is it's send data to all of array and when I click another button it's just replace the selectedAnswer with the clicked button (The following image will explain lot about the problem)

here is my code

Quiz.js (The child component)

```
const answerButtons = decodedAnswers.map (decodedAnswer => (
  <button 
  id={decodedAnswer}
  key={decodedAnswer}
  onClick={()=>props.selectAnswer(decodedAnswer)}
  >

     {decodedAnswer}

  </button>
```

App.js (The parent component)

```
 async function fetchData () {
    const response = await fetch (apiURL)
    const data = await response.json ()

    setQuestions (data.results)
  }
  

  function selectAnswer(questionId, answer) {
    setQuestions((prevQuestions) =>
      prevQuestions.map((data) =>
        data.id === questionId ? { ...data, selectedAnswer: answer } : data
      )
    );
  }  

  const quizElements = questions.map (quiz => (
    <Quiz 
      question={quiz.question}  
      key={quiz.question}
      correctAnswer={quiz.correct_answer}
      incorrectAnswers={quiz.incorrect_answers}
      selectAnswer={(answer) => selectAnswer(quiz.id, answer)}
    />
  ))

  function handleClick () {
    console.log (questions)
  }
  const checkAnswers = <button onClick={handleClick}>Check Answers</button>
```

[image: This will explain the purpose]

so if you can help me with this I would really appreciate it

In case of emergency here is the full code
Quiz.js (The child component)

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import './style.css'
const he = require('he');


function Quiz (props) {
    const [shuffledAnswers, setShuffledAnswers] = useState ([])
    const [chosenAnswer, setChosenAnswer] = useState (null)


    const answers = [...props.incorrectAnswers]
    const correctAnswer = props.correctAnswer

    useEffect (()=> {
        const shuffled = [...answers]
        const ranNumForAnswerMix = 
                     Math.floor(Math.random() * (answers.length + 1))
        answers.splice (ranNumForAnswerMix, 0, correctAnswer)
        setShuffledAnswers (shuffled)
    }, [])    


    const decodedQuestion = typeof 
                props.question === 'string' ? he.decode(props.question) : props.question;

    const decodedCorrectAnswer = 
                typeof correctAnswer === 'string' ? he.decode(correctAnswer) : correctAnswer;

    const decodedAnswers = shuffledAnswers.map (answer => (
        typeof answer === 'string' ? he.decode(answer) : (answer)
    ));

    const answerButtons = decodedAnswers.map (decodedAnswer => (
        <button 
          id={decodedAnswer}
          key={decodedAnswer}
          onClick={()=>props.selectAnswer(decodedAnswer)}
        >

            {decodedAnswer}

        </button>
    ))
    

    return (
        <>
        <div className="quiz-parent">
            <div>
               <div>                        
                    <p>{decodedQuestion}</p>
                    <p>answer: {decodedCorrectAnswer} </p>
                    {answerButtons}
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )

}

export default Quiz
```

App.js (The Parent component)

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Start from './components/Start';
import Quiz from './components/Quiz';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {

  const [isStartScreenShowing, setIsStartScreenShowing] = useState (true)
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState ([])


  const apiURL = 
          'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=9&difficulty=easy&type=multiple'

  
  function toggleStartScreen () {
      setIsStartScreenShowing (false)
      fetchData ()
  }


  async function fetchData () {
    const response = await fetch (apiURL)
    const data = await response.json ()

    setQuestions (data.results)
  }
  

  function selectAnswer(questionId, answer) {
    setQuestions((prevQuestions) =>
      prevQuestions.map((data) =>
        data.id === questionId ? { ...data, selectedAnswer: answer } : data
      )
    );
  }  

  const quizElements = questions.map (quiz => (
    <Quiz 
      question={quiz.question}  
      key={quiz.question}
      correctAnswer={quiz.correct_answer}
      incorrectAnswers={quiz.incorrect_answers}
      selectAnswer={(answer) => selectAnswer(quiz.id, answer)}
    />
  ))

  function handleClick () {
    console.log (questions)
  }

   

  const checkAnswers = <button onClick={handleClick}>Check Answers</button>
  

  
  return (
    <div className="App">

        { isStartScreenShowing &&
          <Start 
            isStartScreenShowing={isStartScreenShowing}
            toggleStartScreen={toggleStartScreen} 
          />
        }

        { isStartScreenShowing !== true &&
        <>
          {quizElements}
          {checkAnswers}
        </>
        }

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: When you debug, in the `selectAnswer` function, what is the value of `questionId`?  When are the values of each `data.id` in the map operation when updating that state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the question object has an `id`? In the screenshot you have attached, there are no values for `id`. If the id is not in the object, it will be `undefined` so and all of the ids will be the same, thus all questions will be updated.